# How to enable app menu in vlc?

Tags: unity, vlc, appmenu

Call it a minor annoiance, but I'd really like if vlc used the app menu instead of displaying it in the main window.

Is there a way to correct this behavior?

I don't really know if this would require patching vlc or if it's something that could be enabled with a plugin. Extra points if you can provide me more info on this.

Comment: You mean like Minimized version for playing Audio files, If so please include that info in question

Comment: No, I mean the that the vlc menubar should be in the appmenu indicator not in the application window.

Comment: Glad that you got your solution, thanks for clarifying  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to a [bug](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946153) in Qt, you cannot enable the global menu in some Qt applications such as VLC. Once the bug is fixed, VLC will use the global menu as usual.

If, however, you use the daily build version of VLC, the global menu works just fine.
You can get it from the [following](https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/master-daily) [PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA):

```
ppa:videolan/master-daily
```