# No VLC Menu in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vlc, appmenu

[image]

I installed VLC via Ubuntu Software GUI. Trying to adjust playback speed but not seeing any menu options in a dropdown or anywhere else.

Is there something I'm missing?

I saw a post here ([How to enable app menu in vlc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178820/how-to-enable-app-menu-in-vlc)) from 2012 suggesting there was a bug with QT. Has this been resolved?

Thanks!

Comment: Your are using the snap version of vlc, it should have  settings available in Tools > Preferences. If you want you can remove it ( `sudo snap remove vlc` ) & install the .deb version ( `sudo apt install vlc`

Comment: Tried this but still not showing any menu options. Not seeing any tools/preferences anywhere :/

Comment: I just don't understand why it would be so complicated to use VLC in Ubuntu. When you click multiple files, rather than adding to a queue, it tries to play them all at once (I've yet ot figure out how to add a number of videos to a playlist).

Comment: While I use 18.04 with unity I booted to live session & installed both the snap & .deb vlc's. In both cases the menus are right in the vlc window, inc. Tools. So you are -  not running Ubuntu,   using some other theme, using some gnome-shell extension or have changed some other vlc setting. For the last one to ck. go to ~/.config & delete the vlc folder. If that doesn't work then you'll need to consider the 1st three.

Comment: Got it, appreciate you taking the time to boot that up. Hadn't considered a gnome theme had edited things. Will research those options

Comment: I just upgraded Ubuntu from 16.04 and 18.04 and I found that I have this problem with what seems to be some, but not all QT apps.  Problems:  FlightGear, Kylin-video, OBS Studio, OpenShot, TeamViewer, VLC.   Not: Audacity (uses Gnome theme), Calibre,PSI Plus (nonstandard menus), Sleepyhead, Wireshark-QT. (I found the apps by threatening to delete qt5-widgets and seeing what else it wanted to remove)  I don't yet know what the cause is, but in all of them, when you click an entry in the top menu bar or right-click for a context menu, the submenu is there but invisible.

Comment: Sounds like maybe my problem's different -- I do see the top menu bar; it's just the submenus that are invisible.  I also found that it only happens on 1 of 3 monitors. I'll guess that it's some bug related to hardware-assisted compositing and the proprietary nvidia driver, but still don't know what is being used to cause some apps to have the problem and others not.

Comment: 1 monitor? How about 1, or 2, or 0, depending on which display (all driven by the same card) I mark "primary"! Odd.